# Meteor Passing Unique Id From Form to Helper

Tags: jquery, meteor

I put this in my template file:

```
<div>
   <label>Category</label>
   {{#each categories}}
      <input id="category_{{_id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{_id}}" name="category" {{hasCategory}} /> {{name}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

My Question is how do I access the input id in my helper:

```
"click #CATEGORY_ID_FROM_TEMPLATE_HERE": function() {
    var category_id = $('#CATEGORY_ID_FROM_TEMPLATE_HERE').val();
    return false;
}
```

I realize it is probably something simple but I am not getting it, even googling it. I know I could use event and access the target property on it, but I want to use jQuery.

Please if someone could assist me in this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
   <label>Category</label>
   {{#each categories}}
      <input id="{{this._id}}" class="example" type="checkbox" value="{{this._id}}" name="category" {{hasCategory}} /> {{name}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

with `this` we refer to instance of each document.

Now on the event, we use the `class selector` example, because `id need to be unique`

```
"click .example": function() {
    //var category_id = $('#example').val();
    //console.log(category_id) 
    console.log(this._id) //this will return the id
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ethaan for your really fast response to my question, I was aware of the 'this' solution but I should have put that remark in the question. Nevertheless your response works too as a solution so I would give you a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Using IDs in this case is unnecessary and results in a lot of negative effects. In particular, if you add two of these templates to your page they will stop working because the IDs aren't unique. Instead, use Meteor's built in ability to access the data context:

```
<div>
   <label>Category</label>
   {{#each categories}}
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{_id}}" name="category" class="category-checkbox" {{hasCategory}} /> {{name}}
   {{/each}}
</div>

"click .category-checkbox": function(event) {
    // Inside here, this refers to the category object
    var category_id = this._id;
    var checkbox = $(event.target);
    return false;
}
```

Edit after your edit:

If you still want to use jQuery to get the relevant element, the correct way to do this is `$(event.target)`.

Comment: you are right that having two of these templates on a page will cause problems, but thats why to differentiate between the two I added a keyword like category in front of it. I was also aware of using event and target property as I mentioned in the question but i did not want that approach. And I was aware of the 'this' route too, but did'nt want that either. But I will give you a point up since a person will get the value out of the input with your solution.